# JPA EmbeddedId becomes null on persist even though object clearly contains propper IDs

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I have an issue when trying to persist a parent with one or more child entities in one transaction. The error does not occur when the parent is already persisted earlier, and I'm only trying to persist the child. The IDs are generated by the Java program, and I am definitely setting the EmbeddedId, as well as the reference in my child to my parent.

The following piece of code is basically my workflow. I'm doing a bunch of sanitizing, but that doesn't affect my IDs.
I did try to debug this by putting a breakpoint in the loop, right before I persist one of the child, and the object did contain every bit of information it needed to. The EmbeddedId is instantiated and populated with both the `parentId` and the `childNr`. Just for some reason, in the insert that is generated by JPA both fields, the `parentId`, as well as the `childNr` are set to null, which obviously causes an exception since they are my primary key.

I did try to call `persist` on my parent before I persisted its children, and I tried to use a Cascade and just call the `persist` on the parent. Both tries ended up with a similar result.

```
em = createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();

int childNr = 1;
for (Child c : newParent.getChilds()) {
    c.setChildId(new ChildId(newParent.getParentId(), childNr));
    childNr++;
    c.setParent(newParent);
    em.persist(c);
} 
em.persist(newParent);
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
```

Parent entity:

```
@Entity    
public class Parent implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PARENTID", nullable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition = "CHAR", length = 20)
    private String parentId;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Child.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<Child> childs;

}
```

Child entity:

```
@Entity    
public class Child implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ChildId childId;

    @MapsId("parentId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENTID", referencedColumnName = "PARENTID", nullable=false)
    @ManyToOne
    private Parent parent;
}
```

Child EmbeddedId:

```
@Embeddable
public class ChildId implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "PARENTID", columnDefinition = "CHAR", length = 20)
    private String parentId;

    @Column(name = "CHILDNR", columnDefinition = "DECIMAL", length = 4)
    private int childNr;

    public ChildId(String parentId, int childNr) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
        this.childNr = childNr;
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Do I have to split this up into two separate transactions? I think something is overriding my EmbeddedId and I cannot figure out what it is. I am a 100% certain that every field of the child instance I'm trying to persist is populated. The EmbeddedId, as well as the reference to my `Parent`.

When I instantiated the EmbeddedId in the no-arg constructor of my `Child`, the `childNr` in the insert statement was 0 and not null anymore. Obviously that doesn't help, but it makes me believe that JPA is doing something in the background that calls that constructor.

Comment: It looks like your code isn't matching your entity. Obviously, there is no ParentId field in Child class.

Comment: I observe that your `Child` entity has two persistent properties mapped to the same database column: `childId.parentId` and `parent`.  How well you persistence provider will handle that probably depends on the provider.  Have you considered using a surrogate key instead?

Comment: @asm0dey You are absolutely right! That mistake happened when I exchanged my horrible entity names to Parent and Child to make them more readable.

Comment: @JohnBollinger unfortunately, the database design cannot be changed, since other applications are already using it.

Comment: @Tmesus did you try to set `cascase=CascadeType.PERSIST` on Parent? Hypothetically it should help you to avoid calls to persist children.

Comment: @asm0dey yes, I did try that but it didn't change anything. The insert-statement still hat null values for both of the id fields.

Comment: You shouldn't 'need' to set the parent ID value in the embeddable, as JPA should pick it up and set it from the relationship. The for loop should be called to set the embeddedIds before persisting any of the objects - I'd recommend setting cascade persist on the parent->Child and just calling persist on the parent once everything has been set.  Otherwise, your parent has a list of children JPA needs to deal with, most of which do not have primary keys set.